# Installing service object for pos .net device

Tags: .net, barcode-scanner, pos-for-.net, service-object

Im a newbie to this and trying to access a motorola ds4208 scanner through my c# program.

All i researched says that I need OPOS drivers installed and "SERVICE OBJECT " to be installed for the device to be listed.

Once its listed I can call getDevices() and it will detect the device.

My problem is as how to install the service object for the scanner.

Any directions would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I am investigating using POS.NET with an existing point of sale.  This article from 2011 indicates some compatibility issues with .NET 4.0 as well as problems with 64 bit compiles requiring the use of 32 bit compiler option.  Also CAS policy conflicts.  It also provides an installation order with Common Controls first then POS for .NET next.  http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2011/06/06/Using-Microsoft-POS-for-NET-in-2011.aspx

Comment: Here is an example project from CodeProject using POS.NET with C# and Visual Studio 2008.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34473/Controlling-a-Barcode-Reader-with-POS-for-NET  There is not anything about installation of components that I see however.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to download the driver\service object from the manufacturer website, in your case i believe this link is the place to start [Motorola Solutions:Scanner Drivers and Utilities](http://www.motorolasolutions.com/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Software+and+Applications/Mobility+Software/Scanner+Drivers+and+Utilities).

Then you will need to install the CCO(Common Control Objects) from here [Monroe Consulting Services](http://monroecs.com/oposccos_current.htm).

Then install Pos for .NET which you mostly already have, sometimes if you don't follow this order of installation it will not work, although its not a rule.